# GIT pre-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a way to change the file that is being pushed to the server using a [server-side pre-receive hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html#serverside_hooks)?

Say I want to add something to the end of a file like:

```
//End of Org
```

each time someone pushes to my repo.

Is there a way you can change the file coming in using [`git hooks`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)?

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) which can operate on the content of each file in order to check if your line is there and add it if not, during the checkout step.

[image]

That would be:

- a smudge script
- able to be replicated when your repo is cloned (as opposed to hooks which are not copied over when cloning a repo unless you use a [template directory](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html#_template_directory))

Comment: How do I get the filter driver copied to each repo when a clone/pull is done?

Comment: @beast: a filter driver is a `.gitattributes` file, managed like any other files, and pushed/pulled like any other file. The smudge script it references can also be versioned.

Comment: right so I have the .gitattributes file setup and in the repo.

I have a *.c filter=test in the .gitattributes file.

How do I get so that

[filter "test"]
        clean = cat
        smudge = cat
is copied to each repo clone/pull so that I don't have to do git config filter.test.smudge cat each time I clone the repo?

If you cannot tell I am fairly new to git and trying to get the same config across multiple computers.

Comment: @beast: You need to replay the setup for your config (unless you are cloning on the same server, in which case a `git config --global` is enough). I usually keep the config commands in a version file, for me to replay after a clone.

Comment: @VonC could you check this!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931921/how-to-add-the-pre-receive-hook-in-server-side-in-gitlab

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness sake: it should be rather obvious from the name that what you are asking for, is simply impossible. The `pre-receive` hook cannot change any files, because it hasn't *received* any yet!

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: This is quite simply nonsense. It is perfectly possible to do what the OP is asking, although it's rather a bad idea.