# Why can git pre-receive hook show recent file change but not diff it?

Tags: git, diff

In trying to write a pre-receive hook which rejects certain kinds of changes to certain kinds of files, I am stumped as to why the following is legal in that script:

```
git show <new_commit>:<file>
```

as is used in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570098/317110) (after having teased out the affected files using diff with --name-only), but not

```
git diff <old_commit> <new_commit> -- <file>
```

I prefer the latter so that I only reject changes introduced rather than patterns already existing in the files, but it generates the error: "unknown revision or path not in the working tree" when executed from this script.

I suspect it has to do with the [ordering of events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618036/317110), since both work at the command-line on my bare repo, but would like to understand the distinction.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618036/317110) points out, when the `pre-receive` hook is executed, no files have been received yet, only which refs should be updates (details on this and other hooks can be found on the [githooks(5) manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)).

Since there is no data with which your old data could be compared, no diff can be created.

Comment: But if no file has been received yet, how can "show <new_commit>:<file>" work?

Comment: @JohnLehmann what exactly does `git show <new_commit>:<file>` print when you call it from that script? Can you paste an example output somewhere?

Comment: The linked answer is wrong. It is not the case that 'pre-receive' means that the files have not yet been received.

Comment: @jwg, yup that's right, the manpage says as much. Must've seen something wrong back then. Feel free to edit the answer, since I don't currently have time to properly research it.