# how to add the pre-receive hook in server side in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I am trying to restrict the binary file (EXE, DLL, PDF) committing in our gitlab. So I need to add the hook to restrict it in globally. How can I do this? Is Pre-receive hook is suitable for this?

Is this place is correct to add the hook?

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive

Any helps appreciated!

Comment: For per-project, use custom hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155063/6309 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html#chained-hooks-support)

Comment: @VonC But I don`t know how to use this. Could you explain briefly?

Comment: I will after work.

Comment: Also I want to add this as globally.

Comment: looking forward for your reply, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, for per-project, use [custom hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155063/6309):  ([Chained hooks support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html#chained-hooks-support))
See the exact steps at "[How can I add hooks to gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155063/6309)", and involve the create of a dedicate `repo.git/custom_hooks` subfolder.

But that is per-repository, not for all repos.
You would need to add that script for each repo of a group.

The `pre-receive` script you would see in the normal `repo.git/hooks` folder is actually a symlink to the `gitlab-shell hook` folder, and it is taken by GitLab to manage the access permission.

Comment: You meant, I need to add the pre-receive hook in each and every repo in server machine?

Comment: @Arunkumar Yes, or at least a symlink to one common script if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a side-wide hook, but it is not very well documented. Gitlab is currently integrating `gitlab-shell` and `gitaly`. So providing instructions is a bit of a moving target, but they are valid as of the release of 12.3.5.

The scripts in `gitlab-shell/hooks/*` scan the current repository and site wide directories. However, the site wide directories will not be created at a clean install and you need to create them yourself.

```
mkdir -p <XXX>/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive.d       # or update.d or post-receive.d
chown git:git <XXX>/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive.d

# link or copy your script of course it needs to be executable by the Gitlab user
ln -s /usr/bin/my-hook <XXX>/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive.d/my-hook
```