# How to use gitlab-shell to "add custom git hooks to any GitLab project"

Tags: shell, gitlab

I'm trying to setup `custom git hooks` with gitlab [similar to the user in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931921/how-to-add-the-pre-receive-hook-in-server-side-in-gitlab?noredirect=1&lq=1). Specifically a pre-receive hook - therefore [web hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) and [CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html) will not suffice.

Most search results [show how to perform this action when admin access to the gitlab host file system is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154384/how-can-i-add-hooks-to-gitlab/24155063#24155063). This mirrors [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html):

> Custom Git hooks must be configured on the filesystem of the GitLab
>   server. Only GitLab server administrators will be able to complete
>   these tasks.

However, the following is later mentioned:

> As of gitlab-shell version 2.2.0 (which requires GitLab 7.5+), GitLab
>   administrators can add custom git hooks to any GitLab project.

I'd like to make sure I understand this correctly, does this line mean one can add `custom git hooks` with gitlab-shell alone - in other words - without file system access?

If so let's assume the following for a gitlab user:

- the user **does not** have an account (admin or otherwise) on the operating system where the gitlab software is installed (can't access relevant portions of the filesystem)
- the user **does** have an account to login to the gitlab system software itself, and this account is assigned gitlab admin level privileges

Will this user be able to add `custom git hooks` to any gitlab project? If so, how is this achieved?

Comment: See the first line of the documentation page you linked: "Please explore webhooks and CI as an option if you do not have filesystem access. "

Comment: Right, this is the line I've partially quoted above - the conclusion being that adding custom git hooks using gitlab-shell simply isn't possible? If this is the case I think it is confusing that the blurb about gitlab-shell and custom git hooks (my second quote above) is there in the first place. It should be re-worded in my opinion. Thanks! @MrTux