# How to use gitlab-shell?

Tags: shell, gitlab

I can't seem to find any information or examples about how to use [gitlab-shell](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell). My initial approach was simply to attempt an SSH session from my development box to the server. I received an error response like [the one from this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/523002/local-ssh-connection-to-gitlab-not-working):

> jacob@mypc: ssh git@git.example.com:
>  
>   PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
>   Welcome to GitLab, jacob!
>   Connection to git.example.com closed.

The error was alleviated by adding the `-T` parameter [like this user does](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/9nqqbe/anyone_else_here_use_gitlab_having_issues_with/):

> jacob@mypc: ssh git@git.example.com:
>   Welcome to GitLab, jacob!

However, as would be expected with the `-T` parameter, I am not presented with a shell. At this point I'm not sure what to do. **How is gitlab-shell supposed to be used?**

Comment: It's not an interactive shell, it's limited to predefined Git commands (git push, git pull).

Comment: @MrTux Any idea about [how to use it for custom hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288620/how-to-use-gitlab-shell-to-add-custom-git-hooks-to-any-gitlab-project)?